# JAXB type Erasure

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, type-erasure, schemagen

I'm trying to create java to xsd for a java type that looks like this.

```
public class MainRequest<E extends AParentType<Person>> extends EObject {
private Transaction tran;
private E e;
private String email;
}

public class SubRequest extends MainRequest<AChildType> {
}
```

where AChildType extends AParentType.

when i try to create a schema for SubRequest. I expect it to substitute 'e' with AChildType, but it retains the AParentType.

Is there something wrong with this ? Is there anyway i can achieve this. Not sure if @XmlAdapter is a solution.

Appreciate help.

Comment: what version of jaxb? Invoked precisely how?

Comment: I don't think `schemagen` works very well, it was always the red-haired step-brother of `XJC`. It's a bit back-to-front, anyway, it's much better to start with a schema and generate java from there, rather the other way around, which is why `schemagen` doesn't get much attention.

Comment: You can put `@XmlTransient` on `MainRequest` and see what happen. Oh one more thing you can generate XSD with JAXBContext#geneateSchema